# Possibilities in Solidity

Tags: solidity, nft, randomness

I want to create an NFT crowd sale contract. I have 4 egg. People will buy them with possibilities, I mean for exp: 1st egg's chance is 1%, 2nd is 5% and so on.

What is the best way of doing this?

Comment: Only way to programmatically simulate probability is using RNGs, in which case you need to use ChainLink's RNG.